# How to test grounding in AC outlets?

Tags: electrical, grounding

How I can test that the ground cable of my AC power outlet is really grounded / correctly grounded ?

Is  a quick test that I can do or an instrument that does just that ?

Also, how is grounding rated if it's rated at all. Some x amount of charge discharged per each second?

I'm well aware that most buildings basically have a ground wiring for each power outlet, and all ends up linked to a metal stick in the ground, but how do I check the grounding when I'm near a power outlet and I don't know anything about the blueprints of the house or anything else ?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I'm not sure what technicalities you are looking for. A proper safety ground is a low-resistance path to earth. It can tested by sending a trickle if current down that path and confirming that the voltage stays minimal. The exact specs for what is acceptable are defined by the electrical codes for your part of the world.

Comment: @keshlam "*A proper safety ground is a low-resistance path to **the source**.*".

Answer (score 2):

There are two, somewhat related problems that can happen to the earthing system in a house

### Your earthing system isn't connected to earth well enough (or at all)

This is mainly a problem due to lightning etc. inducing surges on the power line -- the earthing of your house's power grid limits these surges to a manageable value for other things (like surge suppressors).  Ed Beal's answer covers testing for this, although it's not a terribly high priority to fix.

### Your earthing system isn't connected to the neutral/return well enough (or at all), or is connected *improperly* to the neutral/return

This is the main issue people complain about when they say their house has "no ground".  The *bond* between the neutral (return) and ground (earth) systems at the service entrance is what allows the ground system to serve as a safety mechanism against exposed metal parts becoming energized.  However, it can be defeated by being absent altogether, or by an improper cross-connection between earth and neutral.  There are two tests to perform here, in addition to a visual inspection of the neutral and earthing systems:

1. The energized yoke test -- this involves seeing if a non-contact voltage detector held near the normally earthed yoke of a receptacle is set off.  This test catches a [very dangerous situation](http://ecmweb.com/contractor/failures-outlet-testing-exposed) where the neutral and earth contacts on the receptacle are both inadvertently hot while the hot contact is connected to the neutral -- in North American practice, this is called a "reverse polarity bootleg ground".
2. The earth bond/ground loop impedance test -- a specialized tester called a "ground loop impedance tester" is used for this.  It plugs into a receptacle and measures the impedance it finds between ground and neutral -- this catches other issues like an open ground, or a "bootleg" connection between neutral and ground located at the receptacle.  If one is not available, a voltmeter measurement from neutral to ground *with the circuit loaded* can substitute -- this should read half a volt to a few volts on a properly wired and loaded circuit due to voltage drops in the loaded neutral wire, but will read nearly nothing if a bootleg ground is present at a receptacle.  Unfortunately, bootleg grounds may be present in other places in the electrical system as well, and are far harder to catch when they are, often requiring a lucky visual sighting of the errant wire to find.

Answer (score 0):

The ground in your home is measured in Ohms normally 25 Ohms or less. There are 2 ways to verify the value of the ground (both are very expensive meters). The first is a [clamp on earth test](http://www.tequipment.net/Fluke1630.html?Source=googleshopping&gclid=CILrwrKKx84CFc5lfgoduaQO6g) meter that uses high frequency coupled into the wire and calculates the current from the clamp.
[The second older method](https://www.zoro.com/extech-earth-ground-tester-kit-820-hz-382252/i/G0495056/?gclid=COyn6oqLx84CFcVgfgodsOkBWg&gclsrc=aw.ds) uses multiple points spaced in a line with pins driven in the ground at at least 2 additional points (some testers require 3-4). 
Many homes rely on the structural steel in the concrete for a point of ground plus 1 driven rod 8' long. if no structural steel or metal water pipe a second 8' ground rod needs to be driven 6' or more from the first rod. there are other grounding methods but these are the most common. Both test methods provide similar results when set up properly.